# Series.str.replace() from Vectorized String Methods

Tags: python, regex, pandas, str-replace

In the Vectorized String Methods documentation (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#vectorized-string-methods)...

```
In [204]: s3 = Series(['A', 'B', 'C', 'Aaba', 'Baca',
   .....:             '', np.nan, 'CABA', 'dog', 'cat'])
   .....: 

In [205]: s3
Out[205]: 
0       A
1       B
2       C
3    Aaba
4    Baca
5        
6     NaN
7    CABA
8     dog
9     cat
dtype: object

In [206]: s3.str.replace('^.a|dog', 'XX-XX ', case=False)
Out[206]: 
0           A
1           B
2           C
3    XX-XX ba
4    XX-XX ca
5            
6         NaN
7    XX-XX BA
8      XX-XX 
9     XX-XX t
dtype: object
```

Why, in the .replace() example above, is the 'ba' and 'BA' not selected by the regular expression fed as the first argument in the replace() method and replaced by 'XX-XX'? It seems to me to be saying ^ any character followed by . an a, or dog, replace, starting with that any character, with 'XX-XX ', regardless of case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because 'ba' and 'BA' is not found at the start of string, where alternative has the `^` anchor in `^.a` which asserts the position at start of string.

> Specified by:
> [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: So the regex is only finding the first instance of that condition, replacing it and moving on? (I made a small edit at the end of my question to clarify what I think it's 'saying', but had not considered whether the search is repeated more than once per line.)

So how would I find ALL instances of that condition and replace ALL of them with XX-XX? What changes in the regex? @unihedron

Comment: @Canuckish The regex will match `^.a` (anything except newline followed by an "a" at the start of string) `|`(or) `dog` (character sequence "dog" literally")

Comment: @Canuckish You're welcome. You can remove the anchor, i.e. use `'.a|dog'` instead.